# How to deploy an embedded custom form with camunda modeler?

Tags: camunda

I try to use an embedded custom form in comunda 7. I created a simple task, choose "Embedded or external task form" and form key is "test". Then i create a simple html form and add it to the list of additional files in the menu that pops up when i click the deploy button. I add the form from my desktop and click "deploy". When i start the process a button appeared that says "open external form" but when i click on it i get directed to a location

`http://localhost:8080/camunda/app/tasklist/default/test?taskId=8afac394-f19a-11ec-b810-240a641ca618&callbackUrl=http://localhost:8080/camunda/app/tasklist/default/#/`

and see a 404 Not found error page. The url also dont exist in the "webapps/camunda/app/tasklist" folder. "test" was the form file (test.html) and i referenced it by "test".

Maybe someone can help me out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your case the form key should be embedded:deployment:test.html